# VirtualBox abort guest VM intentionally

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, vagrant

I am wondering if someone knows how to abort a VM (linux box) in VirtualBox 5.0 intentionally? I've googled this to no avail as everyone complains why their VM's get aborted in state. I am recreating such error found by my colleage where his VM has been aborted and error on `vagrant destroy` command. But I can't seem to find how to abort a VM.

**His scenario:**

1. Create a VM `vagrant up`
2. For I don't know reason, his VM got aborted (probably sleeping) then try to destroy his VM while aborted `vagrant destroy -f`

Question: How can I abort a VM intentionally, is this even possible? Thanks!

**UPDATE** included the error on his MacBook

```
# vagrant destroy -f ; vagrant up
==> vmbox: Forcing shutdown of VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["controlvm", "5d15834f-63ad-4085-ac5e-953052e8bf53", "poweroff"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to power off machine
VBoxManage: error: The VM session was aborted
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component SessionMachine, interface ISession
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleControlVM(HandlerArg*)" at line 234 of file VBoxManageControlVM.cpp
```

Comment: Kindly add comment if you find this question somewhat abusive of the rules and/or inappropriate so to give some overview. Thank you for down voting.

Comment: I gave you an upvote, I don't know why someone downvoted it. Here is a link that may help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069908/vboxmanage-error-failed-to-create-the-host-only-adapter) Comment back with your result